# Angular 4 how to set default options for HttpClient for entire application?

Tags: angular

I want to use the same request options for my entire Angular 4 application. In particular I want to pass `withCredentials: environment.xhrWithCredentials` for requests (based on current environment).

But I do not think it is a good idea to set option for each and every request like this:

```
this.http.get('/api', {withCredentials: environment.xhrWithCredentials})
```

Is there a way to set default options for `HttpClient` once for entire app?

Comment: You could think of using angular httpInterceptor refer [this article](https://medium.com/aviabird/http-interceptor-angular2-way-e57dc2842462)

Comment: Well.. You can always override default Http implementation.

Comment: @Injectable()
export class HttpInfraAPIService extends Http {....}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't use it yet, but based on https://angular.io/guide/http you need to intercept all requests and set base properties there.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = req.clone({withCredentials: true /*environment.xhrWithCredentials*/});

        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably want to use a global service "ApiService"

```js
public getApi(endpoint:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/api/'+endpoint, {withCredentials: environment.xhrWithCredentials});
}
```

Then inject this ApiService instead of Http and call getApi() with the endpoint you want.

Comment: But doesn't this meant that I should create similar function for every http method?